# Altium Gerber Top Paste is missing components

Tags: altium, gerber

I just finished the design of my board on Altium, and when I generate the Gerber files, everything seems correct except for the Top Paste File, looks like some components are missing on this file. Any idea of why is this happening?

I used ViewMate to check if there was any problem with the Gerber viewer from Altium but the file looks the same.

Here are some screenshots.

[image: Top Paste]

[image]

It's evident that a lot of components are missing, capacitors and resistors in specific. I want a stencil so that's why I need the Top Paste Layer. I hope you guys can help me out, I've been playing around without any solution.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you check if those footprints actually have a properly defined paste layer? Where did you get them from?

Comment: Hi there, yes I did check that, the footprints are from ultra librarian, some of the capacitors that appear on the top layer (copper) are the same than the ones that do not appear, so I can safely discard that option.

Comment: Maybe check beyond seeing that they are there and see what specific layer they are on and if that layer has been set to export in Gerber. I've found mistakes in those ultralibrarian footprints. Sub in a 2-pin footprint (can be anything) known to work for a part and see if it appears. If it does then the footprint is the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I double checked again the component, somehow was the only one without the paste layer. I just added it again. Anyway, it's solved now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the footprint carefully. The paste layers may be missing or it may be there but not properly defined.

If you're super stumped, substitute in a 2-pin footprint known to work (can be anything) and see if it displays properly. If it does, then the problem is definitely the footprint.